# Hide Installed app icon in android

Tags: android

I have a scenario in which i have to hide few installed apps icon i did try my best but didn't get the problem i think following code work for root devices only.

```
ComponentName componentToDisable =
                  new ComponentName("com.androidbird.lmkt",
                  "com.androidbird.lmkt.Splashscreen");

                  getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                  componentToDisable,
                  PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                  PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

**Logcat:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbird.lmkt/com.androidbird.lmkt.Splashscreen}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=18338, uid=10165, package uid=10140
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:167)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:929)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=18338, uid=10165, package uid=10140
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.setComponentEnabledSetting(IPackageManager.java:2573)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1250)
com.androidbird.dashboard.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5125)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2289)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=18338, uid=10165, package uid=10140
```

you cant hide other application ... for that you need root access... you can hide your app icon

Comment: Yeah i think so but some one says you don't need it that's why i want to confirm it btw thanks